# Python, changing value of a progress bar error

Tags: python

```py
import time

for i in range (1, 101, 1): 
    prog["value"] = 1
    window.update_idletasks()
    lblpro.config(text="Calculating" + str(i)+ "%")
    time.sleep(0.005)

pro["value"]= 100
```

prog = Progressbar(window, Orient=HORIZONTAL, maximum=100, value=0, mode="determinate").place(x=40,y=430)
And I got a error:

> ```
> TypeError : None Type object does not support item assignment
> ```

Comment: Is this your full code? where is `prog` defined? Can you add the line where it is defined to the code, as it will be helpful in solving the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour], read [ask], and update the post to include a [mcve].

Comment: It's hard to understand where the error comes from has you didn't share a minimal reproducible example. However, the issue might be that you misspelled `prog` in the last line of the code.